# WPF DataGridComboBox column with static list of Tuples or KeyValuePairs defined in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml

It's possible to declare the list of combobox items in a DataGridComboBox column in the xaml using a column definition such as

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Gender" 
                        SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Gender, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">

    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
            <system:String>M</system:String>
            <system:String>F</system:String>
        </CompositeCollection>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ItemsSource>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

This is fine if the values in the binding match what we want to display on screen. It's also possible to bind ItemsSource to a Dictionary in code and use `SelectedValuePath` and `DisplayMemberPath` to display one set of values (e.g. Male, Female) whilst using another set of values (e.g. M, F) in the backing store.

Is it possible, without writing a utility class to represent the key-value pair, to define the latter type of items list entirely in XAML? I've tried putting a `Dictionary` in there instead of the `CompositeCollection`, and defining the `CompositeCollection` to contain elements of `KeyValuePair` or `Tuple` but without success- when using the correct namespaces, `Dictionary` and `Tuple` simply aren't recognised, and `KeyValuePair` actually shows in the autocomplete as `KeyValuePair'2` but still isn't recognised when selected (neither is `KeyValuePair`.)

Comment: I don't think XAML supports any kind of generic data type now. `Dictionary` is generic only, so you cannot use that in XAML. Why do you want a Dictionary? To show data, we don't need a dictionary, it's just for looking up by key.

Comment: I don't *need* a Dictionary, it's just the way I've done it in the past where the list has been dynamic. I've come to a ComboBox that only needs to display the same small set of strings in the dropdown, but store the selection internally as an integer. The two ways that are obvious to me, being a Dictionary or a Converter, seem more hassle than this task really should be so I'm looking for a better option.

Comment: why not create your own class and put each item in `CompositeCollection`? (instead of what you do with `string`).

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant by writing a utility class to represent the key-value pair. Still seems inelegant. :)

Comment: at least it would be more readable than what you are trying to make. If you want I think the only way is using something like ***array of array***, or ***CompositeCollection of CompositeCollection***, of course then the `Binding` should be set using indexed path with `[]`.

Comment: What about a simple `enum`? You don't have to create a full-blown utility class, you get your key-value pair and you can easily bind to it...